# What does the -DQT_WEBKIT flag mean in g ++?

Tags: g++

The same project is assembled on different versions of the OS with different flags.
What is this flag?

First OS:

> -g++ -c -pipe -g -D_REENTRANT -Wall -W -Wno-unknown-pragmas -DQT_WEBKIT -D_TESTR ...

Other OS:

> +g++ -c -pipe -g -D_REENTRANT -Wall -W -Wno-unknown-pragmas -D_TESTR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-D` option is a *preprocessor option* and is documented in [section 3.13 *Preprocessor Options*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-D-1) of the [GCC Manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/). (You can also always just run `gcc --help` or `g++ --help` to get help for the options.)

The `-D<name>[=<value>]` option `#define`s the macro `<name>` to have the value `<value>` (or `1` if the value `<value>` is not provided).

So, in your case, it defines the three macros `_REENTRANT`, `QT_WEBKIT`, and `D_TESTR` to the value `1`, in other words, it is exactly equivalent to having

```cpp
#define _REENTRANT 1
#define QT_WEBKIT 1
#define D_TESTR 1
```

prepended to the file being compiled.